# Unit testing @PreAuthorized(hasRole) controller methods

Tags: spring, unit-testing, authentication, spring-security

I'm trying to write unit test for this controller method

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole(#d.code) or hasRole('ROLE_ALL_ACCESS')")
@RequestMapping(value = "{department}/{examination}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String show(ModelMap model, Principal principal, Locale locale, D d) {
    model.addAttribute(service.getItem(d) //THIS CAUSES NULL ON TEST
            .addAttribute(new DateTime())
            .addAttribute(locale);
    return "show";
```

I tried this

```
@Test (expected=AccessDeniedException.class)
public void testShowAccessDenied() {
super.simulateRole("ROLE_STUDENT");
 controller.show(new ModelMap(), Helper.getTestPrincipal(), Locale.getDefault(), new D());
```

But it causes NullPointerException on the marked line, which means test is running the method instead of throwing AccessDeniedException based on the wrong role.

My super test class is

```
 public class AuthorizeTestBase {

private Mockery jmock = new JUnit4Mockery();
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager= jmock.mock(AuthenticationManager.class);

@Before
public void setUp() {
 jmock.checking(new Expectations() {{ ignoring(anything()); }});   
}

protected void simulateRole(String role) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
    PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken pat = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(Helper.getTestPrincipal(), "", authorities);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationManager.authenticate(pat));

}
```

Helper.getTestPrincipal is

```
 LdapPerson.Essence essence = new LdapPerson.Essence();
 LdapPerson user = (LdapPerson) essence.createUserDetails(); 
 return new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(user, "password");
```

I think I'm missing something on mocking authenticationManager. Help me!

Comment: Which is the Marked line?

Comment: See the controller method code and comment there

Answer (score 0):

The NPE is happeing when you try to call the **service**. Your class AuthorizeTestBase doesn't know about any spring beans service/dao etc . So it should load the spring wire configuration. The below is an example.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/applicationContext-test.xml",
                                   "classpath:/applicationContext-ABC-test.xml",
                                   "classpath:/applicationContext-DEF-test.xml",
                                   "classpath:/applicationContext-serviceGHI-test.xml",
                                   "classpath:/applicationContext-securityHIJ-test.xml"
})
 public class AuthorizeTestBase {
.....

}
```

Also please have a look into - [Spring MVC Test Framework](http://spring.io/blog/2012/11/12/spring-framework-3-2-rc1-spring-mvc-test-framework)

Comment: That I could figure out, but the controller method should not be run at the first place since it has @PreAuthorized anotation and the user role is wrong?

Comment: @mjgirl - Well you haven't figure out I am afraid. If you have seen the comment in my answer - How will your application knows about the role and stuff? (("hasRole(#d.code) or hasRole('ROLE_ALL_ACCESS') if the spring configuration is not loaded?

Comment: So I was saying. I should not get NullPointer in this scenario, but getting it because the autentication goes wrong. The problem is now that my real sec-config uses ldap, which retrieves its connection attributes in pom.xml

Comment: @mjgirl - instead of this - private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager= jmock.mock(AuthenticationManager.class); can you use MockAuthenticationManager and try please?